# How to use osmdroid maps in Android?

Tags: android, maven, jar, maps, osmdroid

I am building application and I want to use **osmdroid maps** in it because I have heard that it doesn't require *Google Play Services* to use map.

What I have tried so far?

I downloaded **.jar** files, See the screenshots. But now don't know how to integrate it with my on going project.

[image]  [image]

I have searched on the internet but couldn't find the proper solution. There was written to copy these files into **libs** folder. Is it a libs folder of my project which is **../AndroidStudioProjects/MyProject/app/libs**?

What should I do? I am using Android Studio

Comment: Bare osmdroid will be probably insufficient (lack of markers etc.) Try osmbonuspack https://code.google.com/p/osmbonuspack/ there is also a  tutorial how to use it: https://code.google.com/p/osmbonuspack/wiki/HowToInclude

Comment: @jaroslawj thanks for the suggestion, I will use it but would you tell me how to integrate this api with my project. Where should I copy files and the changes in gradle.build?

Comment: just copy osmbonuspack jar file into libs directory and add it to dependencies in build.gradle. In my case it was 
`compile 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:4.2'
compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-android.1.7.7'
compile files ('libs/osmbonuspack_v.4.9.jar')` slf4j is a requirement for osmdroid as far as i remember

Comment: @jaroslawj Thanks for the help. You could write it as answer.

Answer (score 2):

1. Put osmdroid-android-x.x jar under lib folder of project directory
2. In Android studio, it will reflect under lib folder now Right click it and hit 'Add as library'
   3.Ensure that compile files('libs/smdroid-android-x.x.jar') is in your build.gradle file
3. Do a clean build

Now in MainActivty of your application/module: add the following code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_osmdroid);
        map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.osm_map);
        map.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPQUESTOSM);
        map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        map.setMultiTouchControls(true);
        map.setUseDataConnection(true);
        map.getTileProvider().clearTileCache();
        IMapController mapController = map.getController();
        mapController.setZoom(8);
        GeoPoint startPoint = new GeoPoint(24.084082, 79.892578);
        mapController.setCenter(startPoint);
    }
```

Meanwhile create activity_osmdroid.xml in layout folder and add the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <org.osmdroid.views.MapView android:id="@+id/osm_map"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

finally, you must add permissions to your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: helped me a lot.  UPVOTED!  :)